# Template is flickering when change subscription

Tags: meteor

I hope you help me.Something strange happens when I change subscription. So, data that is not presented in subscription is showed for a little moment. Here my sources:
1. Autorun that wait paging:

```
    template.autorun(function (computation) {
      if (Session.get('factors.page.ready') || Session.get('rules.page.ready')) {
        var factors;
        var userIds = Factors.find({},{sort :Session.get('factors.sort')}).map(function (factor) {
        return factor.creator;
      });
      Meteor.setTimeout(function () {
        factors = Factors.find({},{sort :Session.get('factors.sort')}).fetch();
        Meteor.call('factors.getUserCount', _.pluck(factors, '_id'), function (err, counts) {
          if (err) return;
          _.forEach(counts, function (obj) {
            var factor = _.find(factors, function (factor) {
              return factor._id === obj._id;
            });

            if (factor) factor.userCount = obj.count;
          });
          if(!computation.firstRun) {
              template.factors.set(factors);
          }
        });
      }, 15);

      template.subscribe('users.names', { _id: { $in: userIds } });
    }
    });
```

2. Also paging autoruns:

   ```
   template.autorun(function () {
       var options = Session.get(collection + '.options') || {};
       var sort = Session.get(collection + '.sort');
       var page = Session.get(collection + '.page') || template.page.get() || 1;
       if (!options.limit || typeof options.limit !== 'number') {
         options.limit = 10;
       }

       options.skip = (page - 1) * options.limit;
       if (sort) options.sort = sort;

       // create a subscription with parameters
       sub = Meteor.subscribe(collection, {
         filters: Session.get(collection + '.filters'),
         options: options,
         assignFirst: Session.get(collection + '.assignFirst')
       });
     });

     template.autorun(function () {
       var page = template.page.get() || 1;
       var options = Session.get(collection + '.options') || {};
       var limit = options.limit || 10;
       var visiblePagesNum = options.visiblePagesNum || 7;
       var visiblePagesHalf = (0 | (visiblePagesNum - 1) / 2);
       var visiblePages = [];
       // wait for ready
       if (sub.ready()) {
         count = Counts.get(collection) || limit;
         // get array of pages, i.e. [1, 2, 3...]
         pages = _.range(1, Math.ceil(count / limit) + 1);


         if (page - visiblePagesHalf < 1){
           visiblePages = _.first(pages, visiblePagesNum);
         }else{
           if(page + visiblePagesHalf > pages.length){
             visiblePages = _.last(pages, visiblePagesNum);
           }else{
             visiblePages = _.range(page - visiblePagesHalf, page + visiblePagesHalf + 1);
           }
         }
           // set first page if there is only one
         if (page !== 1 && (pages.length === 1)){
           template.page.set(1);
         }

         Session.set(collection + '.page', page);

         // set amount of pages for pagination
         template.pages.set(pages);
         // set visible pages
         template.visiblePages.set(visiblePages);
         if (collection === 'logs') {
           Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
             Session.set(collection + '.page.ready', true);
           }, 200);
         } else {
           Session.set(collection + '.page.ready', true);
         }
       } else {
         Session.set(collection + '.page.ready', false);
       }
     });
   ```
3. And helper that transfers data on page:

   ```
   factors: function () {
     return Template.instance().factors.get();
   },
   ```

Sorry for my English